# Work Manager doesn't work sometimes in Android Pie

Tags: android, android-workmanager

I am using `WorkManager` for alarms on Android

It works fine but sometimes it doesn't work

Do you have a problem with my source?

```
OneTimeWorkRequest mywork = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker.class)
                            .addTag("timer")
                            .setInitialDelay(calsTime, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

WorkManager.getInstance().enqueueUniqueWork("timer", ExistingWorkPolicy.REPLACE, mywork);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "sometimes it doesn't work"?
Keep in mind that WorkManager doesn't support exact time alarms. Also, on which devices are you seeing these problems, have you tried in the emulator to see if it works correctly?

Comment: In Pi, Work Manager is used instead of Alarm Manager.
So when using the countdown timer, I use the delay of the work manager
Tested on Xiaomi Hongmi Note 7
Thank you

Comment: This maybe a problem with that particular device. Can you please open a bug on the WorkManager public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197